# Play Json transformations, update doubly nested array

Tags: json, scala, playframework, transformation

I have a list of json objects with doubly-nested array of objects which I would like to add new property to:

```
{
    "outer" : [
        {
             ...
             "inner" : [
                 {
                     // add new key-value pair
                 }
             ]
        },
        {
             ...
             "inner" : [
                 {
                     // add new key-value pair
                 }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve it with `Play Json` transformations plugin? FYI, every entry in array (sub-array) can be identified with unique `_id`. Play-Json plugin: `2.4`.

Comment: Are you mapping these to case classes or keeping it as pure json?